sf project convert no longer creates customMetadata folder
Using:
sf project convert source --root-dir OurRootDir --package-name OurPackageName --output-dir OurOutputDir

used to create a folder customMetadata in the output-dir directory. This folder contained all .md-meta.xml files.
For some reason this doesn't happen anymore. This causes issues in the way we deploy all our objects to our org. The files are however mentioned in the package.xml. This causes issues when we deploy OurOutputDir since then the zip file no longer matches the package.xml.
Is anyone familiar with this, or knows to direct me to documentation why this change was made? And maybe a proper solution...?
A colleague of mine still uses an older version of the sf cli, and for my colleague the customMetadata folder is still created.

Mystery solved, we have *.md included in our .forceIgnore. This has been there for months (if not years) but apparently this was never respected in sf commands until a certain update, at least that is my guess.
